# The kernel of the quotient map $R \to R[x]/(ax-1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, proof-explanation, localization

This is a problem from *Algebra* by Michael Artin.

> Let $a$ be an element of a ring $R$, and let $R_0 = R[x]/(ax − 1)$ be
>   the ring obtained by adjoining an inverse of $a$ to $R$. Prove that
>   the kernel of the map $R → R_{0}$ is the set of elements $b ∈ R$ such
>   that $a^n b = 0$ for some $n > 0$.

http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic256346.files/Set%202.pdf

There is a solution in the pdf above (labelled Artin 10.5.14), but I cannot follow it yet. I started to be confused after the third line of the proof. And it seems unclear to express $b$ and the image of $b$ in the quotient ring with the same notation.

Could someone show explicitly what the author is doing after then? Many thanks!

Comment: Can you say exactly what statement it is you don't understand and why?

Comment: @Eric Wofsey Thanks! IActually I cannot follow anything from the sentence $Setting\ the\ constant\ terms \equal$.I do not understand what the meaning of $Setting \the\ constant\ terms\ equal$,and why $α = ab0.\ Furthermore\, abn = 0$ and why must the leading term of $(ax − 1)Q(x)$ would have degree 0.As well as the identity in the last line...

Comment: The link to `isites.harvard.edu` is broken. I'm also unable to find any copy saved on the Wayback Machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f:R\to R_0$ be the map described, which is obtained by restricting the quotient map $\pi:R[x]\to R_0$ to the constant polynomials $R\subseteq R[x]$. If $\alpha\in R$ is in the kernel of $f$, then it is in the kernel of $\pi$, which is the ideal $(ax-1)R[x]$ by definition.  So $\alpha=(ax-1)Q(x)$, for some polynomial $Q(x)$ which we can write in the form $$Q(x)=b_0+b_1x+\dots+b_nx^n.$$  Now we have $$\alpha=(ax-1)Q(x),$$ and remember that this is an equation of polynomials, where the left-hand side is a constant polynomial.  For two polynomials to be equal, their coefficients must be equal.  Expanding out the right-hand side we get $$(ax-1)Q(x)=-b_0+(ab_0-b_1)x+(ab_1-b_2)x^2+\dots+(ab_{n-1}-b_n)x^n+ab_nx^{n+1}.$$
For this to be equal to $\alpha$ as a polynomial, the constant coefficient $-b_0$ must be $\alpha$, and all the other coefficients must be $0$.  That is, $\alpha=-b_0$, $ab_0=b_1$, $ab_1=b_2$, and so on, ending with $ab_n=0$.  Putting these equations together we find:
\begin{align*}
\alpha&=-b_0 \\
a\alpha&=-ab_0=-b_1 \\
a^2\alpha&=-ab_1=-b_2 \\
&\vdots \\
a^n\alpha&=-ab_{n-1}=-b_n \\
a^{n+1}\alpha&=-ab_n=0.
\end{align*}

That is, some power of $a$ multiplied by $\alpha$ is $0$.

(The solution you linked to is basically the same, but has an error where it writes $\alpha=ab_0$ instead of $\alpha=-b_0$.)

Comment: But I think that $\alpha$ is just an arbitary element of the kernel, how can we see that it must be a constant polynomial?

Comment: The domain of $f$ is just the constant polynomials $R\subseteq R[x]$.  We're computing the kernel of $f:R\to R_0$, not the quotient map $\pi:R[x]\to R_0$.